# create a channel and send a message discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am creating a bot on discord, I would like to create a new channel through a command in which an embed with various functions is sent.
I tried several methods, I can get a default message to be sent in the newly created channel but I can't get it to call the command that sends me the embed

this is the embed I want to send in the channel I create via the command (setup.js)

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'setup',
    description: "ruoli con emote",
    async execute(message, args, Discord, client){
        
        const channel = '831573587579371580';
        const playem = '⏯️';
        const stopem = '⏹️';  
        const nextem = '⏭️';
        //const shuffleem = '';
        const loopem = '';
        const volume15 = '';
        const volume30 = '';
        const mute= ''
      
        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
       
        .setColor('#e42643')
        .setTitle('Barman')
        .setImage('https://images4.alphacoders.com/943/943845.jpg') 
        .setFooter('il prefisso del bot è: *');     
        
        console.log('message: ' + message )
        console.log('args: ' + args)
        console.log('Discord: ' + Discord)
        console.log('client: ' + client)
    
           let messageEmbed = await message.channel.send(embed);
           messageEmbed.react(playem);
           messageEmbed.react(stopem);
           messageEmbed.react(nextem); 
           //messageEmbed.react(shuffleem); 
           messageEmbed.react(loopem);
           messageEmbed.react(volume15);
           messageEmbed.react(volume30);
           messageEmbed.react(mute);

           client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) =>{
               if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
               if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
               if (user.bot) return;
               if (!reaction.message.guild) return;
               if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel){
                   
                switch(reaction.emoji.name){
                    case playem:
                        console.log('Pausa / resume');                    
                        client.commands.get('psres').execute(client, message, args);
                        break;

                    case stopem:
                        console.log('stop');                    
                        client.commands.get('stop').execute(client, message, args);
                        break;
                    
                    case nextem:
                        console.log('Skip');                    
                        client.commands.get('skip').execute(client, message, args);
                        break;

                    case loopem:
                        console.log('loop');                    
                        client.commands.get('loop').execute(client, message, args)
                        break;
                    
                    case volume15:                                
                        console.log('volume15');                    
                        client.commands.get('volume15').execute(client, message, args)
                        break;
                    
                    case volume30:                                
                        console.log('volume30');                    
                        client.commands.get('volume30').execute(client, message, args)
                        break;
                    
                    case mute:                                
                        console.log('muto');                    
                        client.commands.get('mute').execute(client, message, args)
                        break;
                
                }    
                } 
           });
           
    }
}
```

this is my creation channel function

```
  if(command === 'setup'){
        var botname= 'DJ Musica' // setup messaggio con reazioni
        message.guild.channels.create(botname,{ //Create a channel
          
          type: 'text', //Make sure the channel is a text channel
          permissionOverwrites: [{ //Set permission overwrites
              id: message.guild.id,
              allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],              
          }]
          
      }).then(channel => channel.send('eccoci ' + message.channel.id))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/#individual-command-files) provides a good method of dynamically handling the commands.

In order to set it up to execute the module, I followed along with the `discord.js` guide and created my own dynamic command handler. With that, I could easily call upon the command and simply execute it.

Code:

```js
const fs = require("fs"); //used to read files
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
//returns array of files in directory that read w/ end of ".js"
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
    console.log(command);
}

client.on('message', message => {
    const prefix = '!';
    if (message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (!client.commands.has(command)) return;

    if (command === 'setup') {
        var botname = 'DJ Musica' // setup messaggio con reazioni
        message.guild.channels.create(botname, { //Create a channel

            type: 'text', //Make sure the channel is a text channel
            permissionOverwrites: [{ //Set permission overwrites
                id: message.guild.id,
                allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
            }]

        }).then(channel => { //main part I modified
            channel.send('eccoci ' + message.channel.id);
            client.commands.get(command).execute(message, args, Discord, new Discord.Client());
        })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken the code to send a message in a channel that is created by the bot is

```
message.guild.channels.create('CHANNEL NAME HERE', { reason: 'Needed a cool new channel' })
.then(channel => {
channel.send('MESSAGE HERE')
})
```

Comment: this is a similar way of sending messages in the channel, my problem however is that I don't want to send a message but I want to start a specific command, in this case the setup.js